# How to play PS3 games in RPCS3 through attract-mode on windows 10?

Tags: ps3, windows-10, emulation

I am wondering: how to setup attract-mode to run games from RPCS3 on Windows 10? I have tried a few tutorials out there on the web but nothing seems to be working. If you have a working fix for this please share it.

Here are some links if you dont know what attract mode or RPCS3 is:

- [rpcs3](https://rpcs3.net/)
- [attract-mode](https://attractmode.org/)

Comment: Can you explain attract mode in the question? I get a security warning when loading the linked page.

Comment: attract mode is a front-end for emulators similar to emulationstation and launchbox and the website is safe I don't know why its giving a warning when clicking the link from the post just try searching attract mode on google and you will see it.

Comment: here is a youtube video showing off attract mode https://youtu.be/u03BfxnN858